# Unity Script and game not syncing after player respawn

Tags: unity, c#

I have a health system for my player that looks like this:

```
public int fallBoundary = -10;
public int Health;
public int numOfHearts;

public Image[] hearts;
public Sprite fullHeart;
public Sprite emptyHeart;

void Update() {
    if(Health > numOfHearts) //Health script works, why does heart display not? 
    {
        Health = numOfHearts;
    }

    for (int i = 0; i < hearts.Length; i++) {
        if (i < Health) {
            hearts[i].sprite = fullHeart;
        } else {
            hearts[i].sprite = emptyHeart;
        }

        if (i < numOfHearts) {
            hearts[i].enabled = true;
        } else {
            hearts[i].enabled = false;
        }
    }
}
```

Unfortunately, after respawn, the hearts do not sync anymore. My debugging showed, that the elements of `hearts` still did their job, resetted and got replaced correctly. However, in my game, nothing changes after the respawn (should reset to full health and change if player gets damaged). For the respawn, I am loading my prefab, which I also checked (everything is there). To avoid confusion: my hearts never reset to 0, but stay at 1.

Player Prefab that loads during respawn

[image: Player Prefab that loads during respawn]

Hearts after respawn

[image: Hearts after respawn]

Comment: In the code you provided, I don't see a point at which you actually change the value of `Hearts` (other than clamping it to below the maximum), which would result in your health bar not changing states at all. Is this being set from outside the code you provided? Also, when your player dies, are you instantiating a new player prefab? If so, you'll need to get a reference to the new player object each time you instantiate a new one.

Comment: Sorry, my naming might be confusing. Health is just the total health the player can have. My health bar consists of the hearts of the array `hearts[]`. When my player dies, I am indeed instantiating a new player prefab. But my script I am running is on my Prefab of the player (and the real one of course), so I don't need to reference it, right? (sorry, I am a little confused at the moment)

Comment: Yeah, I was confused by that. I've posted an answer with my recommendation on how to handle this type of thing. If it helps you solve your problem, please don't forget to vote on it :)

Answer (score 1):

How I normally handle this type of thing is by having my player script store and operate on properties like `Health`, and then have a separate script attached to a Canvas object that simply reads those properties from the player script and displays them on the UI.

Normally, the player script would look something like this...

```
// Attach this script to the player object
public class Player : Monobehaviour 
{
    public static Player ins {get; private set;} // keep a static reference to the current player instance - otherwise known as the Singleton pattern
    public float currentHealth {get; private set;}
    public float maxHealth {get; private set;}
    public float healthPct
    {
        get
        {
            if (maxHealth <= 0) return 0;
            return currentHealth / maxHealth;
        }
    }

    void Awake()
    {
        // if there is already a player object, destroy it
        if (ins != null) 
        Destroy(ins.gameObject);

        // set the current player object to this one
        ins = this;     
    }

    void Update()
    {
        // Here, we edit the values of the player's stats.
        // We do not display them, all of that is handled within the PlayerHUD script.


        if (currentHealth > maxHealth)
            currentHealth = maxHealth; // clamp health to maximum
        else if (currentHealth < 0)
            Destroy(gameObject); // player death
    }
}
```

...And the HUD script something like this...

```
// Attach this script to a game object nested within a canvas and attach the necessary components to it
public class PlayerHUD : Monobehaviour
{
    public Text healthText;
    public Image healthBar;
    public const float healthBarLength = 500;
    public const float healthBarHeight = 20;

    void Update()
    {
        // Here, we read the values of the player's stats and display them however we like.
        // We do not edit them in any way - all of that is handled within the player script.

        if (Player.ins != null) // check if there is a player object in the scene - important so that no errors are thrown between respawns
        {   
            healthText.text = Player.ins.currentHealth.ToString("F0"); // display the numerical value of the player's current health
            healthBar.rectTransform.sizeDelta = new Vector2(Player.ins.pctHealth * healthBarLength, healthBarHeight); // adjust the size of the health bar
            healthBar.color = Color.HSVtoRGB(Player.ins.pcthealth * 0.5f, 1, 1); // adjust the color of the healthBar
        }
    }   
}
```

This way, you know that any inconsistency with the stat values themselves is being caused by the player script, and any inconsistency with the way the stats are displayed is being caused by the HUD script. With it narrowed down, you can attach a debugger to Unity and step through the code line-by-line to figure out what the issue is.